# ajax request remove some text from post variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form to submit an article to database through ajax call.
the forms just 2 fields the title and the article text.
I use tinymce editor on my text area.
the problem happened when I cut text from notepad and put it in the text editor and send the text to the server using ajax as post array.

the post array remove some of the text and I'm sure its not database problem since I make alert for the text before inserting text in database and the text still missing. so the missed text occur when I send the text through ajax its received by php missed.

this is the text

"Terms Governing Use of and Access to the ISCN Website
This website www.iscnsystem.org  ("Website") is an Internet site subservient to the international standards establishment (ISE), competent to give a unified global code for the certificates and documents as a service to the Internet community.

By using this Website, you agree to be bound by the Terms , conditions and privacy policy of Use of this Website ( "Terms of Use") and the ISE Privacy Policy ( "Privacy Policy"). If you do not agree with the Terms of Use or with the Privacy Policy, do not use this Website."

when I print it through javascript its complete when I use ajax and send it to php then return it to javascript it will be like this:

"Terms Governing Use of and Access to the ISCN Website
This website www.iscnsystem.org"

the other part is missing

any ideas????

code:
the ajax request:

```
$("#submit_par1").click(function() {
    pass = 1;
    if(!$("#titlepar1").val()) {
        pass = 0;
        $("#titlepar1_error").val("required");
    }
    if(!tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()) {
        pass = 0;
        $("#textpar1_error").val("required");
    }

    if(pass==1) {
        var values = $("#par1_form").serialize();
        var tiny = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/functions.php",
            dataType:"text",
            data: "tag=update_article&fortext="+tiny.stripSlashes()+"&" + values,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                if(data.mess=="success") {
                    alert(tiny);
                    alert("saved");
                } else {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

the php function to handle the request:

```
function update_article($dbh) {
    $data = array();
    $text = preg_replace('/<!--.*?--\>/','',$_POST['fortext']);
    $title = $_POST['titlepar1'];
    $id = $_POST['article_id'];

    $sql = "UPDATE pargs SET title=:title,text=:text WHERE id=:id";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":title",$title);
    $stmt->bindParam(":text",$text);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $data['mess'] = "success";
    } else {
        $data['mess'] = "fail";
        $data['desc'] = implode(' - ',$stmt->errorInfo()); 
    }
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: show us your code please.

Comment: how do you get the text from tinyMCE?

Comment: i get it complete as i say i try to alert it using javascript and it was complete, the missing part happened when i send it to php and the php variable will have the text missing before i put it in database

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debugger;` keyword at the place you want to stop execution and try to find what happens. Or use `console.log(data);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: var tiny = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();     alert(tiny) it complete then send it to php through ajax as post array $text = $_POST['tiny'], $text now have missed text

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of special chars in your text, could it be that the first '(' of ("Website") kills the string you trying to pass?

I tried the following code and the complete text was passed.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['textinput'])){
  $testtext = $_POST['textinput'];
  echo $testtext;    
}

echo("<form role='form' method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>"); 
echo("<textarea name='textinput' cols='50' rows='5'></textarea>");
echo("<button type='submit'>Send</button>");
echo("</form>");  
?>
// PHP version 7.1.2
```